# How do you determine, using RegExp, whether or not a substring is between parentheses?

Tags: javascript, regex, string, brackets, parentheses

Might be a duplicate; I thought this question had to have been already asked, but I searched and couldn’t find one.

**How do you determine, using RegExp, whether or not a substring is between parentheses?**

Say I want to check if the text “fox” is surrounded by parentheses in the following sentence:

```
The (quick) brown fox jumps (over the lazy) dog.
```

I tried this RegEx, but it tests true when “fox” is actually not parenthesized but does have parentheses to its left and right:

```
\(.*?fox.*?\)
```

I tried it with negative lookbehind and negative lookahead, and it doesn’t work either:

```
\(.*?(?<!\)).*?fox.*?(?!\().*?\)
```

Comment: Sorry, I realised after that my comment wasn't useful, so you would like (brown fox jumps) to be matched as true, correct?

Comment: @AndreaOlivato Yes.

Comment: `\([^\)\(]*fox[^\)\(]*\)`

Comment: Basically you require there are no parenthesis within the parenthesis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way to guaranteed that the word exists in inner parentheses only without existing in something nested:

https://regex101.com/r/UlQpM6/1

`\([^()]*fox[^()]*\)`

`\(` - Open

`[^()]*` - 0 or more of any character that isn't parentheses

`fox` - fox

`[^()]*` - repeat pattern

`\)` - Close

Answer (score 1):

This will match any term in parenthesis:

```
\(.*?\)
```

The **(quick)** brown fox jumps **(over)** the lazy dog.

This question mark will ensure that the regex is 'lazy' and will only match the first instance of a closing parenthesis.

Removing the question mark like this: `\(.*\)` will give you the following match, which is probably not what you want:

The **(quick) brown fox jumps (over)** the lazy dog.

If you literally only want to match "(fox)", then the correct regex is:

```
\(fox\)
```

You can use an online regex tester or text editor to answer these kind of questions.